# How to change font color of matautocomplete options

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I want to change font color of mat-option displayed inside autocomplete panel.

I have defined style inside root style.css

```
::ng-deep .mat-option-text {
  color: red !important;
}
```

[image]

However when I set the color property in browser inspect element panel I see the change

**template.html**[image]
What changes should I do in template class or style.css to change the font color of mat-options.

```
<label>Search names</label>
<input type="text"
       placeholder="search name"
       aria-label="Number"
       matInput
       [formControl]="myControl"
       [matAutocomplete]="auto">
     
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{option}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

**template.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-matautocom',
  templateUrl: './matautocom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./matautocom.component.css']
})
export class MatautocomComponent implements OnInit {

  names: string[] = ['ghui', 'ustu', 'caty','momo', 'rekh', 'john', 'kemp'];
  myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]> | undefined;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }
  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
 
     return this.names.filter((option) =>  {
       console.log(filterValue)
      option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue);
      return option;
    })   
   
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you please create stackblitz demo of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global **style.css** is just a plain, non-Angular, or at least non-encapsulated style sheet. You should **remove `::ng-deep`** so it would work.

---

### Solution 1: Remove `::ng-deep` in global style.css.

> style.css (global)

```
.mat-option-text {
  color: red !important;
}
```

[Sample solution 1 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nxkevb)

---

### Solution 2: Place the styling rule in the CSS file for `MatautocomComponent`.

> matautocom.component.css

```
::ng-deep .mat-option-text {
  color: red !important;
}
```

[Sample solution 2 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-skmwav)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

::ng-deep input.mat-input-element { color: red; }

or this

::ng-deep .mat-option.mat-active {
color: red; }